# Delete elastic search dynamic template

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, kibana

I accidentaly changed my default mapping as

```
{
"template": "*",
"mappings": {
    "_default_": {
        "properties" : {
          "message": {"type":"string", "index": "analyzed"}
        },
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "my_template": {
                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                    "mapping": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
   }
```

and now every new index has all string field as not_indexed. I would like to delete this dynamic template and change everything back. My goal was set not_indexed to certain fields.
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If you know what you had previously in your default template, why don't you simply override it with `PUT /_template/your_template_name` ?

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch do you run and how did you ingest the data into Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using sense/kibana then use...

```
DELETE _template/{template_name or id}
```

Using CURL...

```
curl -X DELETE localhost:9200/_template/{template_name or id}
```

Can refer the link below

[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-templates.html#delete](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-templates.html)

For re-indexing the data after correcting the template, use

`POST /_reindex
 {
   "source": {
   "index": "old-index-name"
 },
   "dest": {
   "index": "new-index-name"
 }
}`

Comment: This also deletes the index  curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/{index} and thanks for the answer!

Comment: This didn't worked on ES 6.8, won't downvote because might work in other versions.

Answer (score 0):

@lakhani69 's solution didn't worked for me on elasticsearch 6.8, what I did was:

```
curl --location --request POST http://localhost:9200/index_name/_mapping/mapping_name --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
    "dynamic_templates": [] }'
```

This updated the dynamic template to an empty array.